# Why can't I make anonymous posts within a group anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Contacted the admin and he told me that the anonymous posting feature is available and activated, and that he hasn't deactivated it for me. [This](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/971901733511000164/997975623819608115/Skarmavbild_2022-07-16_kl._23.18.27.png) is only what's visible to me.